# Enum type in python eve schema

Tags: python, enums, database-schema, eve

I am an amateur in the python Eve framework, but I am using it for development purpose. However, I don't know how to have a enum type in the schema. I mean the syntax in python Eve for this data type.

So, how do I express this in python eve schema?

```
"tts" : {"enum": ["show","hide"]},
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [allowed](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#allowed) rule.

```
"tts" : {"type": "string", "allowed": ["show", "hide"]}
```

Comment: I figured this out soon after I wrote a question. But then I forgot to write the answer. But thank you for confirming the same.

Comment: Yep, glad you did. Just keeping a lead to follow for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use custom data types feature in Eve. You can add new data types by simply adding `_validate_type_<typename>` methods to your subclass. Consider the following snippet from the Eve source code.

```
def _validate_type_objectid(self, value):
""" Enables validation for `objectid` schema attribute.

:param value: field value.
"""
if isinstance(value, ObjectId):
    return True
```

This method enables support for MongoDB ObjectId type in your schema, allowing something like this:

```
'schema': {
   'owner': {
      'type': 'objectid',
      'required': True,
   },
}
```

Comment: have you tried with different enum type? If yes, can you post that example?

Comment: No, i haven't tried it yet. I just have read it in documentation. You can ask Sir Nicola for that !